# How can I link to an external Dart library containing the constructor for my web component?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I've been following the Dart web-ui codelab. When I embed dart source code inside a web component `.html` file, I'm not getting any static analysis or autocomplete support in the Dart Editor (there's an open bug for this http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7449 ). Hence, I'm looking for a temporary workaround by using the src attribute.

According to the spec, the src attribute is supported for web components in Dart:
https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/spec.html#behavior. I tried linking to an external Dart library: given a `foo.html` web component for

```html
<element name="x-foo-component" constructor="FooComponent" extends="div">
```

I'd like to link to a separate `foo_embed.dart` file in the same directory as my web component, which defines `FooComponent`, by adding:

```html
<script type="application/dart" src="foo_embed.dart"></script>
```

within `foo.html`. Following the spec's suggestions, `foo_embed.dart` needs to be a Dart library, and would contain:

```dart
library foo_embed;
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
class FooComponent extends WebComponent {
    ...
}
```

When I try this, running `build.dart` (from these instructions http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/tools.html) ends up only putting `foo_embed.dart` in `out/` and there's no `out/foo.html.dart` generated for importing in `application.dart`.

As expected, pasting the contents of `foo_embed.dart` as an inline script inside `foo.html` directly (as done in the codelab) works with `build.dart`, and I can launch my webapp in Dartium, so I don't seem to have any other syntax problems in my project.

Do I probably have a simple syntax mistake somewhere? Or is this a temporary limitation of the Dart web components compiler? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.

This works for me:

**lib/foo.dart**

```dart
library foo;

import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

class FooComponent extends WebComponent {
  var foo = 'asddfg';
}
```

**lib/foo.html**

```html
<element name="x-foo" constructor="FooComponent" extends="div">
  <template>
    <input value="{{ foo }}" />
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="foo.dart"></script>
</element>
```

**example/test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="components" href="packages/foo/foo.html" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>

    <script type="application/dart">main() {}</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I open up Dartium and go to `.../example/out/test.html` and I see an input with the data bound to it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think my problem was fixed by upgrading web_ui and changing my import. After deleting my old `web/out/` directory, renaming `foo_embed.dart` to `foo.dart`, and rerunning `build.dart` with web_ui 0.2.10+2, I now don't even see a generated `out/foo.html.dart` file. As a result, I changed my import to `out/foo.dart` in `application.dart` (from the codelab's import of `foo.html.dart`) and it's working!  Glancing at 0.2.10+2's changelog mentions a change to build.dart so maybe that fixed my issue?)  I'll accept your answer since it does indicate external scripts work.